# Caching a GET request for audio with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, audio, cache-control

I have a PHP script that responds to a GET request for audio resources.  An HTML5 Audio tag requests an audio file such as:

```
<audio src="get_audio.php?f=fun" preload></audio>
```

There is no need for the user to download that same audio file every time so I would like to cache it.  In my PHP file I have:

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=2419200");
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");

...

echo file_get_contents($path);
```

but when I view the Network tab of Chrome developer tools I see that it re-downloads the audio clip everytime rather than saying "from cache" and if I look in the Response headers I do see the Cache-Control header that I set.  Why would it ignore this? Amidoingitright?

Comment: Try with header("Expires: Mon, 26 Dec 2050 00:00:00 GMT");

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did this in PHP, but try adding:

```
header("Pragma: public");
```

above the cache-control header.

I also think you need the expires header:

```
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2419200) . ' GMT');
```

Other than that you could start using the get_headers() function in PHP to debug where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a header in the second request called `If-Modified-Since:`?

This is what you need to catch, parse and respond to - if you don't want to send the file again, you respond with `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified`. If you are using Apache, you can check for the header in the result of [`apache_request_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php). If you are not using Apache, you may find it hard to handle this - you will probably have to find a way for the web server to set the headers as environment variables, so they are available in `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER`. There is a way to do this in Apache using mod_rewrite (see latest comment on page linked above), so there is probably a way to do it in other server environments as well.

Caching in HTTP 1.1 permits (and indeed, encourages) this behaviour - it means that the cached copy will always be up-to-date.